# $\omega$-consistent in Gödel I

Tags: logic, incompleteness, provability

In a very accessible form one could state the first incompleteness as follows:

### Incompleteness Theorem I

Assume that $\textbf{PA}$ is consistent. Then there is a sentence $\phi$ such that

1. $\textbf{PA}\nvdash \phi$ and
2. if $\textbf{PA}\vdash\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(\overline{\phi}) \Rightarrow \textbf{PA}\vdash\phi$, then $\textbf{PA}\nvdash\neg\phi$,

where $\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(y)$ is the "is provable in $\textbf{PA}$" predicate, i.e. $\exists x . \textsf{Prov}_{\textbf{PA}}(x,y)$.

### $\omega$-consistence

My question is about the relation between the assumption given in 2. and the *$\omega$-consistence* of $\mathbf{PA}$, since one can state Gödel I like above but with the $\omega$-consistence as assumption instead.

The definition I know is the following:

There is no formula $\phi(x)$ such that $\mathbf{PA}\vdash\exists x.\phi(x)$ and simultaneously that we have for every $n$: $\mathbf{PA}\vdash \neg\phi(\overline{n})$.

I've tried a few times, always running into the syntactic negation of the assumption. At least I would like to know if it is equivalent at all!?

Thanks!

Comment: The original version of Gödel's theorem required $\omega$-consistency because of his particular solution.  This requirement was reduced to consistency by Rosser using an 'ordering' trick (rather than 'there is no proof of $\phi$', it says 'if $\phi$ is provable, its negation has a shorter proof').  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick.  I'm not sure if it explicitly implies the equivalence of the two forms of the theorem, though - that is, I don't know of any models of one that aren't models of the other.

Comment: I might weaken my question into: can I conclude the above assumption from $\omega$-consistency? (Thanks for your comment)

Comment: I'm a bit confused; what are you trying to conclude from $\omega$-consistency? $\omega$-consistency is (strictly) stronger than 'just' consistency so anything that can be concluded from consistency can certainly be concluded from $\omega$-consistency.

Comment: From $\omega$-consistency I want conclude $\textbf{PA}\vdash\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(\overline{\phi}) \Rightarrow \textbf{PA}\vdash\phi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption in 2. indeed follows from $\omega$-consistency: Consider the formula $\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(x,\overline{\phi})$ in the free variable $x$ expressing that $x$ codes a proof of $\phi$. If $\textbf{PA}\vdash \textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(\overline{\phi})$, then $\textbf{PA}\vdash \exists x. \textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(x,\overline{\phi})$, so $\omega$-consistency implies the existence of some $n$ such that $\textbf{PA}\not\vdash\neg\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(n,\overline{\phi})$, so $\textbf{PA}\vdash\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(n,\overline{\phi})$ by the soundness of the coding $\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}$. Now, in the meta theory you can decode this $n$ and check whether it is indeed a proof of $\phi$ in $\textbf{PA}$ - if it is, fine, and if it is not, the soundness of the coding would also give $\textbf{PA}\vdash \neg\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(n,\overline{\phi})$, hence an inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Still I don't get the idea, especially: why does $\omega$-consistency implies the existence of some $n$ such that ... ? This is of course what I'm looking for but I don't see how to deduce it.

Comment: Well... if I accept the following, I can understand: If $PA\nvdash \neg\phi(\overline{n})$ then $PA\vdash\neg\mathsf{Pr}_{PA}(\overline{\neg\phi(n)})$ **and then(?)** $PA\vdash\phi(n)$. But why should this hold? This would be negation-completeness?  (EDIT: wrong negations)

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I didn't use the assumption of $\omega$-consistency in precisely the way you stated it! However, I hope the argument can be rescued: by $\omega$-consistency, $\textbf{PA}\vdash\exists x.\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(x,\overline{\phi})$ implies that there exists some $n$ such that $\textbf{PA}\not\vdash\neg\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(n,\overline{\phi})$. But then, by the soundness of the coding of $\textsf{Pr}$, we have $\textbf{PA}\vdash\textsf{Pr}_{\textbf{PA}}(n,\overline{\phi})$, and then it goes on as above.

Comment: Ah! It's the primitive recursive again. So we have: "n is a prove for $\phi$" is wrong iff $PA\vdash \neg \mathsf{Pr}_{PA}(n,\overline{\phi})$. And hence it follows. Thank you!